# How to generate multiple unrepeated random variables with a fixed non-uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, random

So for a given discrete distribution, say (0.2, 0.4, 0.4), it would be easy to generate one random number that follow this distribution.

However, what about to generate multiple unrepeated random numbers from it?

e.g. from distribution (p1 = 0.2, p2 = 0.4, p3 = 0.4), if I generate

(1,2) with p12 = 0.2,

(2,3) with p23 = 0.6,

(1,3) with p13 = 0.2.

I'm able to have the marginal distribution of

p1 = (p12 + p13)/2 = 0.2,

p2 = (p23 + p12)/2 = 0.4,

p3 = (p13 + p23)/2 = 0.4.

which is same as the given distribution.

Any idea to build a generator to accomplish this in terms of a general distribution? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the problem as a set of linear equations, you will be able to express it using a matrix equation. For instance:

```
|1/2 1/2  0 |   |p12|     |p1|
|1/2  0  1/2| * |p13|  =  |p2|
| 0  1/2 1/2|   |p23|     |p3|
```

Now you can invert the matrix to get:

```
|p12|   | 1  1 -1|   |p1|
|p13| = | 1 -1  1| * |p2|
|p23|   |-1  1  1|   |p3|
```

In your example this will produce:

```
|p12|   | 1  1 -1|   |0.2|   |0.2|
|p13| = | 1 -1  1| * |0.4| = |0.2|
|p23|   |-1  1  1|   |0.4|   |0.6|
```

So, `p12 = p13 = 0.2` and `p23 = 0.6`.

Comment: Thanks! But what if we have n variables and we are choosing an group of m variables? For sure that we may solve it by linear equations. However if n and m are relative big, then it may not efficient to do this. I am wondering if there is an random generator can generate these groups with given marginal distribution, am I clear? Thanks

Comment: As you stated the problem it is equivalent to solving a linear equation system. So solving it is the same as solving the system. Note however that "my" solution is general in the sense that it works the same for the general case where `(p12 + p13 + ... + p1n)/(n-1) = p1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! so I understand to choose the group of m variables from n variables, we can try to solve the linear systems to know exactly probabilities of each group and then generate it from some generating method. e.g. In my example, once I know p12 p13 and p23, I'm able to generate 12, 13 or 23 with this probabilities.

Comment: (Cont.) While I don't know if there is a way to generate 12, 13 or 23 without knowing their exact probabilities. I tried to generate them in turns, like to produce the first variable by its marginal distribution and then generate the next one by distribution conditional on the first variables, but it doesn't work since it gives anl overall biased result...

Comment: @XiHe The method I depicted in my answer addresses the question you posted and is a little bit more general (see my comment above.) If your problem is different or harder, you should edit the question and rephrase it.